# Use Lightning Components in Visualforce Pages using URL Parameters

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I want to pass a parameter to a visualforce page that creates a lightning component that uses that parameter for catching records calling an apex method and then prefilling fields on the lightning component.

Here is my code:

VFP

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="someDivId" />
    <script>
    $Lightning.use("c:SomeApp", function(){
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:SomeComponent",
            {
                "accId" : "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.accId}"
            },
            "someDivId",
            function(cmp){
                // set parameters for the component cmp
            }
        );
    });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

LIGHTNING APP 'SomeApp.app'

```
<!-- <aura:application access="global" extends="force:slds" implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasSObjectName"> -->
<aura:application access="global" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasSObjectName">
    <aura:attribute name="accId" type="Id" />
    <c:SomeComponent accId="{!v.accId}" />
    <aura:dependency resource="c:SomeComponent" type="COMPONENT" />
</aura:application>
```

LIGHTNING COMPONENT 'SomeComponent.cmp'

```
<aura:component controller="SomeComponentController" implements="force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName">
    <aura:attribute name="accId" type="String" />
    Passing Parameter: v.accId: {!v.accId} <br />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="accItem" type="Account" default="{'sobjectType': 'Account', 'Name': 'Account Name current'}"/>
    Value filling: <force:outputField aura:id="accCompanyNameCurrent" value="{!v.accItem.Name}"/>
</aura:component>
```

LIGHTNING COMPONENT CONTROLLER 'SomeComponentController'

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.getAccount(component, component.get("v.accId"));
    }
})
```

LIGHTNING COMPONENT HELPER 'SomeComponentHelper.js'

```
({
    getAccount : function(component, accountId) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAccountById");
        action.setParams({
            "accId" : accountId
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(result){
            component.set("v.accItem", result.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

APEX CONTROLLER

```
public class SomeComponentController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account getAccountById(Id accId){
        return [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :accId];
    }
}
```

If I am calling some page like this '/apex/LC4VF?id=0014E00000JJHL7', I get this result:
    Content Starts Here
Passing Parameter: v.accId: 
Value filling:

If I use the first instead of the second line of SomeApp.app, and I call '/c/SomeApp.app?accId=0014E00000JJHL7' I get this result:
Passing Parameter: v.accId: 0014E00000JJHL7
Value filling: Test Account

How can I fix this?

Comment: The way I understand is that - when you open the app from URL, it works fine but doesn't work when you load through Vf?

Comment: When opening the VF you are passing the account id in `id` parameter in URL but accessing it using accId - `{!$CurrentPage.parameters.accId}`. You may want to correct this.

Comment: @SantanuHalder: Thx... :)